# choose to edit submitted form through link-lists

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a somehow dump question but I can't figure out a solution. I want a user to be able to edit his submitted forms. That's why I query them according to owner's id

```
all_reqs = Webrequests.objects.filter(own_id=u_id)
```

and load them to template with:

```
   {% for a in all_reqs %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ a }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
```

Now what I can't manage is when the user hits one link with one of his previous submitted forms, the corresponding submitted form to be loaded. How can I catch the id of the form that the user chose? Maybe catch the link id with js and then find form id? But how can I assign ids to links with this django template for-loop? Any other ways to do what I want will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you defined any URLs for editing Webrequests?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to load the from through an AJAX call using jquery.

Your path of thoughts was right. Just add the id of the object on the link.

```
<a href="#{{ a.pk }}" id="{{ a.pk }}">{{ a }}</a>
```

I'd like to add it to the href attribute but I've seen people who rather add it to the id attribute.

Then just bind an onClick event to the tags, read the id, and build a url based on the fetched id.
When you have a valid url, you can send a GET request to django and ask for a form back.

```
$("a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var options = {
        url: "http://host.com/webrequests/" + id
    };
    $.when($.ajax(options)).then(function(data) {
        // show the form which should be in data on your page
    });
}
```

Comment: cool! The main functionality works but what do u mean with  "show the form which should be in data on your page"?Because of json? I was intending to re-render the submitted form(that also means a different view-template) with an instance of the object(submitted form).

Comment: No, I just return a html template which has all the rendered form elements. You could replace $.ajax with $.load for such a task.
You could let your view code return json if the form is valid and from there you could render the returned json data onto your page by replacing it with the submitted form.